# Style checked Radio button and checkboxes with CSS

Tags: css, radio-button

I am trying to style the checked radio buttons and checkboxes with CSS.

```css
.radiocheck:checked~.square {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<label class="square">
       <input type="radio" class="radiocheck" name="test"/>
       <span>Radio number one</span>
    </label>
</br>
<label class="square">
       <input type="radio"  lass="radiocheck" name="test"/>
       <span>Radio number two</span>
    </label>
```

If the radio is checked, I want the background around the radio and the label to be green.